# Error when connecting to SQL Server in deno: 'cannot find module crypto'

Tags: node.js, sql-server, deno

I'm trying to port a nodejs MS SQL Server application to deno. I'm using the node compatibility library to allow the use of npm mssql package:

```
import { createRequire } from "https://deno.land/std/node/module.ts";
const require = createRequire(import.meta.url);
const sql = require('mssql')

async () => {
    try {
        await sql.connect('mssql://user:pwd@host/database')
        const result = await sql.query`select * from the_table`
        console.dir(result)
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('Error:', err)
    }
}
```

However I'm getting an error:

> error: Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'crypto' Require stack:
>
> - C:\WORK\LEARN\DENO\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js
> - C:\WORK\LEARN\DENO\node_modules\tedious\lib\tedious.js
> - C:\WORK\LEARN\DENO\node_modules\mssql\lib\tedious.js

Note: upgrading to the latest version of mssql helped, getting a different error, 'unable to find module tty', which I think I can figure out.

Comment: No idea, but any reason you are using `select *` it's really not ideal

Comment: Does it work if you temporarily turn off encryption, e.g.: `await sql.connect('mssql://user:pwd@host/database?encrypt=false')`? If so you may have a very old (pre-6.0) or broken installation of `tedious` so you could try upgrading/reinstalling that.

Comment: Indeed, 4.3.0. Upgraded to 6.3.1 and getting a new error: Unable to find module 'tty'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The crypto library internal to Node is used internally by the mssql library, however this isn't fully ported to Deno yet as you can see here

https://deno.land/std@0.83.0/node

Comment: Thx, edited the question after the upgrade of mssql to the latest version.

Comment: Sadly, the answer still stands. Node compatibility is still very early in development and lacking in a lot of areas. I think the biggest issue here however is the fact that there is no Sql Server driver for Demo yet though